# PHP - override an output, multiple config

Tags: php, if-statement

I have an echo:

```
echo 'Hello world';
```

and there are two places where I can mange if this echo will visible or not, I can check them using:

```
global_option('show_echo');
```

and

```
post_option('show_echo');
```

Pleae tell how to override `global_option` from `post_option`, Like:

In `global_option('show_echo')` echo was set to hidden, and visible in `post_option('show_echo');` then output the echo.

How to do I make a `else if` which give priority to  `post_option`, mean  `post_option` can override `global_option`.

Suggest me a simplest way to achieve this

Comment: What does your code look like at the moment? Where are you having problems?

Comment: repeating same code multiple times: `if (global_option('show_echo') && post_option('show_echo')){...}elseif(! global_option('show_echo') && post_option('show_echo')){..}` like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need a function which implements the order of priority:

```
function check_config( $key) {
    // Your question is unclear as to the exact logic necessary here
    $post = post_option( $key);
    if( isset( $post)) return $post;

    $global = global_option( $key);
    if( isset( $global)) return $global;

    return false;
}
```

Then just call it with:

```
if( check_config( 'show_echo')) {
}
```